# Battery Drain, S type Jaguar

Tags: jaguar

I've done all the tests and found that when I remove the 40A fuse from the rear fuse box the reading drops from 1.17 to .50  (2002 S type Jaguar)
Could it be the fuse box itself.
 Thanks

Comment: What is the unit of the reading? Amperes? Milliamperes? Even 0.5 A is too high drain, and 1.17 mA is perfectly acceptable, even remarkably low in fact.

Comment: Amperes.Starts at 1.17 amps and drops to 0.5 amps when I take out the 40A fuse from the box.

Comment: What's the 40A fuse connected to? Try and check some more for reducing the current leak. It's the best way to get some clues. You can disconnect the radio and other devices with a stand-by function to isolate the problem better.

Comment: Thanks Bart, I've done all of that, and the only time I get a reduction is when I pull the 40A fuse. I have replaced it with a new one and still get the draw. Thats why I wondered if the box itself could be the issue.

Comment: It won't be the fuse box at fault, unless it is wet.   Are there interior lights on when you are running your tests?

Comment: Do you have a power distribution diagram? What does the 40a fusible link feed?